# Convert Centos shutdown VM to KVM on another Centos server

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, vmware-vsphere

I would like to convert a Centos VM with two hard disk to KVM on another Centos server.

list of two vmdk files of two Hard Disk::

[uslv-addbld-c1:a2dc-vnx01:vg09] Uslv-aNMbuild-01/Uslv-aNMbuild-01.vmdk

[uslv-addbld-c1:a2dc-vnx01:vg09] Uslv-aNMbuild-01/Uslv-aNMbuild-01_1.vmdk

Answer (score 5):

You can use StarWind V2V Converter for this purpose https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter.

It is capable of converting virtual machine files from various formats like VHDX, VMDK, IMG and QCOW and does virtual hardware patching during conversion. Should do the job for you.

Comment: Did they add Linux support? Last time I've checked it was Windows only ;(